TypeScript: [Country, State] wherein the State's auto-complete options changes based on the inputted Country
Here is my sample code:
const AUSTRIA = ['Vienna', 'Raiding'] as const;
const GERMANY = ['Berlin'] as const;
const testCountries = {
    Austria: AUSTRIA,
    Germany: GERMANY
} as const;

type CountriesType = typeof testCountries;
type CountryStateType<T extends CountriesType> = 
  [keyof T, T[keyof T][number]]; // error!
//          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type 'number' cannot be used to index type 'T[keyof T]'.

const countryAndState: CountryStateType<CountriesType> = ['Austria', 'Raiding'];


This code snippet below is working, and it is the expected behavior for countryAndState[1] referencing the CountryStateType:
const StateBasedOnCountry: CountriesType['Austria'][number] = 'Raiding';

Why is there an error and how can I fix it?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! • Please [edit] to make your example have at least two keys if you're going to use keyof T. • Screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions. • I'd think you might be looking for the approach shown in this playground link. If so I could write up an answer or find a suitable duplication source. If not, what am I missing?

Good day @jcalz, The link you provided in the playground link is indeed the same behavior I was experiencing.

I'm afraid I don't understand your comment or your edit at all, sorry. What do you mean by "the duplication"? What do you mean "the same behavior I was experiencing"? Why did you include my suggested solution in the question? Please remove my code from the question if it solved your problem (solutions don't belong inside the questions); I'll write it as an answer. If it didn't solve your problem then please comment to clarify. Sorry again about the communication barrier.

Sorry If I've made it confusing, it partially solves the problem hence I've commented "the same behaviour I was experiencing" because If I add another Country in testCountries, the State of the added Country will be included in the list of states TypeScript auto-complete regardless of the chosen Country.

Here is the playground link)

TypeScript complains about the value being Berlin, but it doesn't remove it in the auto-complete suggestion.

The type you want is ["Austria", "Vienna" | "Raiding"] | ["Germany", "Berlin"] (pls [edit] to mention germany/berlin in the q). If TS's autocomplete behavior is not to your liking there's not much I can do about that directly; see ms/TS#46457. There are indirect approaches like a helper function as shown here, but that's out of scope for your original question (you've edited it to be about "auto-complete" but that's scope creep). How should I proceed here?

The snippet you've provided in the playground link suffices my question. However using a helper function may include some minor performance issues(idk), I'll accept your first snippet as the answer. Thank you @jcalz!

The error happens because the generic constraint T extends CountriesType doesn't mean that T is exactly CountriesType; it could be any possible subtype or extension of it, adding any properties whatsoever:
interface Foo extends CountriesType {
    abc: boolean;
}
type Z = CountryStateType<Foo>; // allowed, oops

As you can see T[keyof T] might not have a number index signature (boolean certainly doesn't) and thus T[keyof T][number] is invalid.

To fix that I'd suggest you constrain T to something less tied to CountriesType. If you want T to have an array of strings at every property, you can express that as T extends Record<keyof T, readonly string[]>:
type CountryStateType<T extends Record<keyof T, readonly string[]>> =
    [keyof T, T[keyof T][number]]; // okay, no error here anymore

type Z = CountryStateType<Foo>; // error
//                        ~~~ <-- Types of property 'abc' are incompatible.


You're still not done, though. The type [keyof T, T[keyof T][number]] doesn't properly express the correlation between each key of T and the corresponding acceptable strings:
type Y = CountryStateType<CountriesType>;
//  type Y = ["Austria" | "Germany", "Vienna" | "Raiding" | "Berlin"] 

This type allows cross-terms like ["Austria", "Berlin"].  If you want to fix that you'll need to distribute [K, T[K][number]] over the union for K in keyof T. One way to do this is with a distributive object type as coined in microsoft/TypeScript#47109:
type CountryStateType<T extends Record<keyof T, readonly string[]>> =
    { [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K][number]] }[keyof T]

type Y = CountryStateType<CountriesType>;
// type Y = ["Austria", "Vienna" | "Raiding"] | ["Germany", "Berlin"]

And that's the correct type. This is the answer to the question as asked (or at least as originally asked).

Of course you'll find that IntelliSense autosuggest/autocomplete doesn't work the way you want.  You still get cross-term suggestions (although if you accept such suggestions there will be an error as expected). This is a known bug in TypeScript, as reported in microsoft/TypeScript#46457. Maybe it will be fixed in some upcoming version of TypeScript. Until then you can either work around it, possibly with a generic helper function:
const countryStateType = <T extends Record<keyof T, readonly string[]>>() =>
    <K extends keyof T>(k: K, v: { [P in K]: T[P][number] }[K]): CountryStateType<T> => [k, v]

const another = countryStateType<CountriesType>()("Austria", "");
//                                                           ^^ <-- you get autocomplete here

Or you can just live with it, and try to be content with the knowledge that the problem is TypeScript's and not your code's.
Playground link to code

Thank you very much! Really appreciate it!
